# How to validate this canadian zip code expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a registration form, what I'm trying to do is to show an error if a user selected USA as a country but put in a Canadian Zip Code.

```
if (ddCountry.SelectedValue == usValue 
    && Regex.Match(TextboxZipCode.ToString(),"^[abceghjklmnprstvxyABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][abceghjklmnprstvwxyzABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] {0,1}[0-9][abceghjklmnprstvwxyzABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$").Success)   
{
  // Show error.....
}
```

That's my code, the `regex` expression I found by googling, that expression validate canadian zipcode. For whatever reason when I test it, it skip right over my if statement, when I selected USA for the country with a valid canadian zip code.

Comment: This seems like an odd validation choice - why not just show an error if they select US and don't have a valid US zip code? (`$[1-9][0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$`).  In any case, you should start by inspecting the returned value of `TextboxZipCode.ToString()` - It could give you valuable insight into why your matching isn't working.

Comment: I will change my expression and see if that works, it's weird though, I ran the debugger and the zipcode is coming in right with that regex expression. Not sure why it's not working

Comment: You should give us the test zip code you're using so we can compare it to the Regular Expression.

Comment: Not sure what code you are referring to, I'm using that regex expression and I tested with a regex tester, it regconized canadian zipcode whether if the user enter space or no space, example K1A 0B1 or K1A0B1.

Comment: ^[abceghjklmnprstvxyABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][abceghjklmnprstvwxyzABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] {0,1}[0-9][abceghjklmnprstvwxyzABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$

Comment: Ah, no - I can read your regular expression in your code.  I wanted to know what the output of `TextboxZipCode.ToString()` was.

Comment: How can I post a screenshot of my debugger?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - one thing: the first part of a US zip code is \d{5}. 0 is a perfectly valid starting number (it represents New England).